# Deleting top 100 records from database via NHibernate using linq

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

Is there a way to delete top 1000 records from database via NHibernate using ling , something similar like Take(100) when u are fetching data?

Comment: Please show us your attempt so far.

Comment: i have tried this '_session.Query<Token>().Where(x => x.Expiry < expiredTime). Take(100).DeleteAsync(cancellationToken)'  and  but had no luck when there are less then 100 records in db.

Comment: Define 'had no luck'.